# Rewrite url in c# web.config like we have in .htaccess

Tags: c#, asp.net, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to have rewrite URL when any one try to access .mp4 files available in some folder on web server. I have only able to found the solution in php with .htaccess using Apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /secure
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ video.php?h=$1&t=$2&v=$3
RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.(flv|mp4)$ - [F]
```

Here any one try to access .mp4 or .flv file with url `clip.baseUrl/hash/timestamp/clip.url`, url get resolved to `video.php?h=$1&t=$2&v=$3`

can we do something like this in c# using web.config? Can we forbid direct access to file .mp4.

Comment: DO you know IIS ? You can do this through IIS .

Comment: I have tried googling around, but no luck !! can u provide me some sample link or some working example posted as answer

Comment: Check the answer below by @Harry.

Answer (score 0):

I think all needed is here, from installing url rewrite module on IIS to writing a rule:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

you have to write IHttpModule module class and in that class create OnBeginRequest(object o, EventArgs args) method. in this method you can rewrite URL. But you have to mention it in Web.config as module.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the web.config file in your site.

For example Redirect your site to HTTPS:

```
<rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

You need write this rule into <system.webServer> tag.
Here have some examples: https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/